# How to change the size of the axis values in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following Matplotlib plot:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

price_values = [[4.2],
    [4.1],
    [4],
    [3.8],
    [3.9],
    [4.2],
    [4.5],
    [4.8],
    [5.2],
    [5.2],
    [5.2],
    [5.6],
    [5.2],
    [5.1],
    [5.3],
    [6],
    [6.2],
    [6.3],
    [6.2],
    [6],
    [5.5] ,
    [5.2],
    [4.8],
    [4.6]]

sample = np.asarray(price_values).squeeze()
ecdf = sm.distributions.ECDF(sample)

x = np.linspace(min(sample), max(sample))
y = ecdf(x)
plt.step(x, y)
ax=plt.gca()
ax.set_xlabel("Price [Cent/kWh]", fontsize = 14, labelpad=8)
ax.set_ylabel("Cumulative frequency", fontsize = 14,labelpad=8)
plt.show()
fig = plt.figure(linewidth=3, figsize=(7, 4))
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=140)
plt.savefig('C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Diagramm_EDF.png', edgecolor='black', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

I would like to change the size of the values in the x and y axis (not the labels). I tried the following `ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=140)` but this does not work. The `labelsize` does not have any effect. Further, I would like to increase the linewidth of the diagramm. Any suggestions how I can do that?

Comment: Try this: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,4));ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=20);ax.step(x, y);ax.set_xlabel("Price [Cent/kWh]", fontsize = 14, labelpad=8);
ax.set_ylabel("Cumulative frequency", fontsize = 14,labelpad=8);plt.show()`

Comment: @r-beginners: Thanks r. Where exactly do I have to insert your suggested code and what do I have to remove instead of this?

Comment: Note that when you call `fig = plt.figure(linewidth=3, figsize=(7, 4))` you are creating  new  empty figure.  You could replace everything from `plt.step` till `plt.savefig` in your existing code with r-beginners' suggestion.  Further, note that `plt.savefig()` should come just before `plt.show()`, because `plt.show()` erases the plot after closing its window.

Comment: @JohanC: Thanks Johan for your comment. It helped. Do you know how I can make the empirical distribution function start from the very left of the x-axis?

Comment: `ax.margins(x=0)`?

Comment: Cool, thanks JohanC for your help. I really appreciate it :-)